# Need help in returning the Date field in Django models

Tags: python, django, rest, django-models, django-rest-framework

**models.py**

```
class Add_Timelog(models.Model):
    
    project=models.ForeignKey(Project,on_delete=CASCADE,related_name='project')
    project=models.ManyToManyField(Project)
    client=models.ForeignKey(Client,on_delete=CASCADE,related_name='client')
    client=models.ManyToManyField(Client)
    Job=models.ForeignKey(Add_Job,on_delete=CASCADE,related_name='Job')
    Job=models.ManyToManyField(Add_Job)
    Date = models.DateTimeField(max_length=10)
    Hours=models.TimeField(null=True)
    
    
    def __str__(self):
        return self.Date
```

*TypeError at /api/Add_Timelog/
**str** returned non-string (type int)
Request Method: GET
Request URL:    http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/Add_Timelog/
Django Version: 2.2.12
Exception Type: TypeError
Exception Value:

**str** returned non-string (type int)*

This is the error I received. The solution what I was expecting is to receive the date inputted by me in the database and receive the value as date (integer) not a string

Comment: unrelated, but you seem to have overwritten attributes by redefining them.  `project` can't be both a `ForeignKey` and a `ManyToManyField`, it's just going to be the last one defined.

Comment: @Zoro D  It can be helpful for you, I have answered here,https://stackoverflow.com/a/71735107/17562044

Answer (score 4):

`__str__` must return `string` and you are returning `DateTimeField` value.
Convert that value to `string` in your `Add_Timelog` model as

```
def __str__(self):
    return str(self.Date)
```

More details on [**str**[Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/ref/models/instances/#str)

Comment: Hii..I have tried what you said and got this error     
ValueError at /admin/App/add_timelog/1/change/
Invalid format string