# How can I filter out date created task in my task list

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-views, django-templates

I'm trying to show the date-created tasks in my list in HTML.

Models.py:

```py
class Task(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True, blank=True)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    description = models.TextField(max_length=1000, blank=True, null=True)
    complete = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
```

And this is my HTML in Django:

```html
<div class="task-items wrapper">
    {% for task in tasks %}
    <div class="task-wrapper">
        {% if task.complete %}
            <div class="task-title">
                <div class="task-complete-icon"></div>
                <i><s><a class="task" href="{% url 'update-task' task.id %}">{{task}}</a></s></i>
                <br></br>

            </div>
            <a class="delete-link"  href="{% url 'delete-task' task.id %}"><i class="fa-solid fa-delete-left"></i></a>
        {% else %}
            <div class="task-title">
                <div class="task-incomplete-icon"></div>
               <a href="{% url 'update-task' task.id %}">{{task}}</a>

            </div>
            <a class="delete-link"  href="{% url 'delete-task' task.id %}"><i class="fa-solid fa-delete-left"></i></a>
        {% endif %}
    </div>
    <div class="emptylist">       
        {% empty %}
        <h3 style="text-align: center; line-height: 3;">No task in list! Let's create your task</h3>
    </div>
    {% endfor %}
</div>
```

For example, for each task I create, it must show the title with the date created, and doesn't matter if it is complete or incomplete. I just can show the title and how do I do that show the date?[image]

Comment: `{{ task.created }}`?

Comment: You have created `DateTimeField`, do you want only `date` to display?

Comment: you have to use values `{{ task.created }}` , `{{ task.title }}`, etc. OR in model you would have to create `__str__` which returns text with date and title.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use *[DateField()](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/ref/models/fields/#datefield)*<sup>django-doc</sup> directly. But if you have defined `DateTimeField` so you can use `@property` decorator and show `date` in the format like `1-7-2022` as you shown in the picture.

Create `@property` in your `Task` model like this:

```
class Task(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True, blank=True)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    description = models.TextField(max_length=1000, blank=True, null=True)
    complete = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    
    @property
    def get_only_date(self):
        date_object = self.created
        year = date_object.year
        month = date_object.month
        day = date_object.day
        return f"{day}-{month}-{year}"
```

Then, use anywhere in your `template` file as property in loop:

```
{% for task in tasks %}
{{task.get_only_date}}
{% endfor %}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
```

please remove auto_now_add=True, then you will get DateTime picker in your template.

Answer (score 1):

```
 <div class="task-items wrapper">
    {% for task in tasks %}
    <div class="task-wrapper">
        {% if task.complete %}
            <div class="task-title">
                <div class="task-complete-icon"></div>
                <i><s><a class="task" href="{% url 'update-task' task.id %}">{{task.title}}-{{task.created}}</a></s></i>
                <br></br>
                    
            </div>
            <a class="delete-link"  href="{% url 'delete-task' task.id %}"><i class="fa-solid fa-delete-left"></i></a>
        {% else %}
            <div class="task-title">
                <div class="task-incomplete-icon"></div>
               <a href="{% url 'update-task' task.id %}">{{task.title}}-{{task.created}}</a>
               
            </div>
            <a class="delete-link"  href="{% url 'delete-task' task.id %}"><i class="fa-solid fa-delete-left"></i></a>
        {% endif %}
    </div>
    <div class="emptylist">       
        {% empty %}
        <h3 style="text-align: center; line-height: 3;">No task in list! Let's create your task</h3>
    </div>
    {% endfor %}
</div>
```

Currently, you are displaying a string representation of you `Task` model, which, I'm assuming is set to showing the title of your task. You need to

1. display the title and date separately
2. change your `Task` representation to return a string formatted with title and time

I would prefer (1), because it gives you much more control. If you want to go with (2), you'll need to add a `__str__` or `__repr__` method.

Comment: Any differences between the __str__ and __repr__ method?

Comment: `repr` returns the _unambiguous representation_ for the object while `str` returns the _string representation_ of the object. eg. `repr(3) and repr('3')`. https://stackoverflow.com/a/2626364/5950394

Answer (score 0):

My recommended method is to use your «created» variable on your template to show the date.

Like for example, I have a model called «post_created_on»,

```
class Profile(models.Model):
  post_created_on = models.DateTimeField()
```

and I want to show it on my template.

```
<h5>This is a post.</h5>
```

So then I'm just use use my «post_created_on» variable on your template to show the date.

```
<h5>This is a post. Created on: {{ task.post_created_on }}</h5>
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

```py
class Task(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True, blank=True)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    description = models.TextField(max_length=1000, blank=True, null=True)
    complete = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
```

```
{% for task in tasks %}
    {{task.created.date}}
{% endfor %}
```

You can use this way without coding any other properties.

Comment: Absolutely, but it will display date in another format that is `july 7, 2022`.